# Which Magento 1 caches should be cleared after installing an extension?

Tags: extensions, cache

As a rule of thumb, which Magento 1 caches should be cleared after installing an extension?

Comment: in backend , you can go to `system > cache management` & click on `flush magento cache` & logout - login......

Comment: Logout is only really required if the ACL needs to be rebuilt... such as adding a new tab in System Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, especially for large websites, flushing the cache from the Admin can be a major process (its much easier to clear the entire cache with ssh). Especially websites with tons of pages, rebuilding the full page caches can take quite a bit of time.

The absolute minimum caches required to flush really depend on the extension.

### **Configuration:**

Used to store extension info including everything in the etc directory. Configuration cache is also required to  be cleared in order to run installation scripts. ***ALWAYS Required.***

### **Layout:**

Used to define which blocks (and templates) are loaded for any given page. ***Required only if new extension includes a layout file.***

### **Blocks HTML output:**

Cached blocks that are pre-rendered and reused for multiple sessions and users. ***Required only if new extension configures 1+ blocks to use the cache.***

### **Full Page Cache:**

Similar to the Blocks HTML output above, this feature pre-renders entire pages. (Enterprise, Extension, V2) ***Required if new extension includes any frontend elements.***

### **Translations:**

Caches the results of translation functions (`echo $this->__('Something');`)  ***Required if website uses translations***

### **Collections Data:**

Not really sure... assume a database optimization.

### **EAV types and attributes:**

Caches the EAV models and attributes including any custom product attributes. ***Required if extension adds/modifies any EAV model***

### **Web Services Configuration:**

Caches the API XML files including WSDL. ***Required if extension includes API additions***

Answer (score 1):

If you flush the full Magento cache that should do it!

(Top right-hand corner) then log out and back in!

Comment: Does "Flush Magento Cache" clear all cache types? What about Cache Storage, Images, Swatches, and JavaScript/CSS?

Comment: You can find buttons for image cache on the cache management page. If all else fails you can either type rm -rf cache in the var folder in your magneto root or clear redis if you use it by typing redis-cli flushall